# Why is socket.getOutputStream() returning null?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, arduino-uno

I am trying to create an android app to communicate with an Arduino Uno R3 using a HC-05 Bluetooth Transceiver. When I try to use getOutputStream() on my open socket in openBT() it returns null.

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter =     BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
OutputStream mmOutputStream;
InputStream mmInputStream;
DataOutputStream out;
String LEDOn = "zero";
String msg = "zero";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.myLabel);

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    // If there are paired devices
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        // Loop through paired devices
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            if (device.getName().equals("HC-05")) {
                mmDevice = device;
                mTextView.setText("Connected to " + mmDevice.toString());
            }
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            // mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
        try {
            openBT();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    } else {
        discover();
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (LEDOn == "zero") {
                LEDOn = "one";
            } else {
                LEDOn = "zero";
            }
            try {
                sendData();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    });
}

public void discover() {
    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    };
    // Register the BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

void openBT() throws IOException {
    final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("4eb3ab89-05e4-4180-b530-964c7ed2d83e");
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    mmSocket.connect();
    try {
        if (mmSocket.isConnected()) {
            mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        } else {
            System.out.println("mmOutputStream = " + mmOutputStream.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
}

void sendData() throws IOException {
    try {
        msg = LEDOn;
        mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

On my Arduino side the code looks like this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>// import the serial library

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(2, 3); // RX, TX
int ledpin = 13; // led on D13 will show blink on / off
char BluetoothData; // the data given from Computer

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.println("Bluetooth On please press 1 or 0 blink LED ..");
  pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (bluetooth.available()) {
    BluetoothData = bluetooth.read();
    if (BluetoothData == 'one') { // if number 1 pressed ....
      digitalWrite(ledpin, 1);
      bluetooth.println("LED  On D13 ON ! ");
    }
    if (BluetoothData == 'zero') { // if number 0 pressed ....
      digitalWrite(ledpin, 0);
      bluetooth.println("LED  On D13 Off ! ");
    }
  }
  delay(100);// prepare for next data ...
}
```

Any help at all is appreciated. I have been scouring this site and google for hours trying to find answers.

Comment: You are blindly calling  openBT(); even when your device is not found.

Comment: You are calling  openBT(); and hence opening the bluetooth socket on the main thread. You are sure this is allowed? 'Normal' sockets can only be opened in a thread.

Comment: I al pretty new android development and programming for bluetooth so I didn't know where else I could put the openBT(); call.

Comment: That has nothing to do with android or bluetooth. Don't you see that the code always calls openBT? You should do that only if your device is found. You are checking if your device is there already. So take the consequences.

Comment: So there is some confusion here. Put the call in a thread or async task.

Comment: You're ignoring IOExceptions. You've presented no evidence that he event described in your title is even happening at all. I suspect what is really happening is a NullPointerException somewhere due to the issue raised by @greenapps.